# How to change background color of each row in list view?

Tags: android, android-listview

My app contains 1 list view, data source is 1 sqlite table, when i hold long click on any row in listview it will show me 1 menu option to change the color of that row, for this i have used  onContextItemSelected function, on selecting menu option it will call 1 function change_color. What should i write in change_color function so that i can change row bg color.

```
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.add(0, PROCESSED_ID, 0, R.string.menu_processed);
    }



    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case PROCESSED_ID:
            AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                    .getMenuInfo();

            change_color();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Call your method as :*

```
change_color(pass_your_list_view, pass_selected_position_of_list_view);
```

And define change_color() as:

```
private void change_color(ListView listView, int position) {
    listView.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
}
```

Hope this will help.

***Edited***

Define a variable a position

```
public static int position;
```

And replace your code as

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add(0, PROCESSED_ID, 0, R.string.menu_processed);

    // Get the info on which item was selected
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    // Retrieve the position at where you long pressed
    position = info.position;

}



public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case PROCESSED_ID:
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                .getMenuInfo();

        change_color(getListView(), position);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer,but it shows me nullPointerexception at line listView.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

Comment: Ok. How are you calling this method? Show me that line. And you are extending ListActivity or Activity?

Comment: extending ListActivity. i am calling function same as u shown,iam using getSelectetItemPosition & getListView function to get position & Listview , these functions r called in onContextItemSelected function befor switch case loop. data source for listview is 1 sqlite table

Comment: no, position value is returning as -1. is it possible that i can use id instead of position?

Comment: No, this is the position of row at you long pressed. I am updating my answer how to read long pressed row position. Wait...

Comment: sorry,I cant because it requires at least 15 reputation, mine is only 11

Answer (score 0):

refer to this tutorial [Colored Row in List View](http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/android-%E2%80%93-applying-alternate-row-color-in-listview-with-simpleadapter/)