# How can i update listview background dynamically

Tags: android, listview, handler

I have tried various methods but none of them is working, what i what is changing the background image of cell of listview for this i have different images for cell. The content remain same. This is what i have tried yet.

```
    CountryList.post(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
             CountryList.invalidateViews();    
        } 
    });
```

// and this one also.

```
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
             CountryList.invalidateViews(); 
         }
    });
```

As i dont content to be reloaded.

[image]

Comment: when you want to change background? on list item focus or on something else?

Comment: i want the cell item background to be changed. Its not onFocus.

Comment: when exactly you want to change background but?

Comment: did you call setBackgroundResource?

Comment: hope it helps you: 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683621/how-to-change-background-color-of-each-row-in-list-view

Comment: there is a theme changer button when i click it changes the background of cells.

Comment: Then why don't you be more specific while asking question. It was wastage of others time actually.

Comment: ok...i have got the solution basically what i did to get each view via getview at ith index and then changed the background of view.

Comment: What background are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can iterate over child components of list-view and get background of each one of them and change their background, for example get child at and so on.