# Set selection of a Linear Layout in A Scroll View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I am inflating a row multiple times in a scroll view linear Layout.i am trying to change the background color of the row which the user selects.But i am selecting the row only in some area it is changing the background color of the row .I am not getting why it is happening.Please help me.

**ScrollView XML**

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainScroll"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainData"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

**InnerLayout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/resultLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundcolor"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="25 Sep 2013" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/id4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**BackgroundColor.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item
 android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@color/grey" />
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/itemselected" />
<item android:state_selected="true"
 android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@color/itemselected" />
</selector>
```

**Color.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="grey">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="itemselected">#EDEDED</color>
</resources>
```

Image as [Image Link](http://s22.postimg.org/5d0lxpck1/Image.png)

It's working on selection but it is not filling the complete height of the layout.Please help me to find the issue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this way you can do this

```
final LinearLayout tripdetailsdata = (LinearLayout) inflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.linearLayout1, null);
            final LinearLayout trip_data = (LinearLayout)tripdetailsdata.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);

            trip_data.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    trip_data1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    trip_data.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    trip_data1=trip_data;
                }
            });
```

Comment: ok  i am trying this what will be tripdetailsdata and trip_data which layout it will be

Comment: first will be your main Layout and second one will be your LinearLayout inner layout

Answer (score 0):

try changing the width/height of the innerlayout's linear layout to wrap_content?
Also, it would help if you posted your code.

Also, I should probably say that for what it looks like you're trying to do, you should probably be using a list view, not a linear layout inside a scroll view.

Comment: what i am not getting you

Comment: change the in innerlayout.xml, change the width / height to wrap_content (of the root LinearLayout)

Answer (score 0):

Try below as your **Inner Layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/resultLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#F00"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="25 Sep 2013" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="coloumn 2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Coloumn 2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/id4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Change android:background="#F00" with android:background="@drawable/backgroundcolor" in top linear layout

Comment: see it is not showing in the complete hieght of the row it not filled

Comment: Are you using any background image with horizontal lines on it?

Comment: dynamically i am addig that lines while infalting

Comment: Try giving height of layout to 40dp (hit & trial), if it did not work post your full code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37988/discussion-between-rahul-and-brontok)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use [Custom listview](https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr&ei=Z3RCUp6wLMjArAfv54GwDg#q=custom%20listview%20in%20android) Instead of trying to repeat a `Linear Layout` content in `scrollview`. Here also you can achieve same task with more flexible. Here you have to [override `getView`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217178/change-listview-item-background-color-but-keep-the-default-selector-style) method to change particular row's background color. Also you can use [ContextMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683621/how-to-change-background-color-of-each-row-in-list-view).

Comment: i don't have to use ListView.i know about listview but i don't have to use listview

Comment: May I know why you din't want listview.

Comment: i don't want to get away from the problems.if i have started with this i will end with this .ListView i don't want to use

Comment: @Gunaseelan he is a dude :D

Comment: Okay Rahul. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use `ListView` instead of `ScrollView` and `LinearLayout`. Because `ListView` have both properties of them. So why don't you make a try?

Try following steps..

1) Implement `onItemClickListener` to your list view like below.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(
            AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int position, long arg3) {
                adapter.setSelectedPosition(position);
    }
});
```

2) Now, in `CustomAdapter` class, write following code

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.special_item_layout, null);

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);

    if ((adapter.getSelectedPosition()) == position) {
        relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.BackgroundColor);
    } else {
        relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.transparent);

    //other code
}
```

I placed `transparent` color if item is not selected. You can put any resource as per your requirement.

Note

Your list must have `singleChoice` option in layout. And no any background.

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice">
</ListView>
```

Comment: brother i want have to do this in ListView.It's an order to implement this as i am doing help me in that way please

Comment: @Rahul, Just remove `ScrollView` and `LinearLayout` from your main layout. and take `ListView` instead. You have your `item` layout which is going to be used in your list. You can find some easy example http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: i don't have to use Listview for this that's why i asking you there will be some way so that we can do this as listview

Comment: @Rahul, I don't know why you don't want to use that. but this will require more time to do so.. can you tell me the reason why you don't want to use `ListView`? What is in your mind you are thinking for ScrollView with LinearLayout?

Comment: brother first i have done this in a ListView.After when the seniors reviewed my code they said we don't need to use ListView u have to inflate a layout dynamically.so i did after that i am stucked in this issue please please help me @chintan.please

Comment: @Rahul, my dear, if you read carefully my code, you can see this line `inflater.inflate(R.layout.special_item_layout, null);`. This is what you need. This will dynamically provide layout my friend. This is called inflating. I think you should ask your senior person why he has not suggested this thing..